# Problem on DataFrame to Dictionary while multiple values in single key

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DataFrame with two columns. I want to convert this DataFrame to a python dictionary.

DataFrame:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"A":["A1","A1","A2"], "B":["B1","B2","B3"]})
print(df)
```

I tried to convert DataFrame to dictionary with **A** columns as Key and **B** as values with below code:

```
df.set_index('A').T.to_dict('list')
```

Output is like

> {'A1': ['B2'], 'A2': ['B3']}

I didn't understand why 'B1' isn't in the list? And how will I get this 'B1' value in the list pairing with 'A1' key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because column `A` has duplicate entries, while creating a dict, it tries to set two keys with `A1`, hence the first value is overwritten.
If you had something like this, it would not be an issue:

```
>>> df= pd.DataFrame({"A":["A1","A2","A3"], "B":["B1","B2","B3"]})
>>> df.set_index('A').T.to_dict(orient='list')
{'A1': ['B1'], 'A2': ['B2'], 'A3': ['B3']}
```

---

**EDIT**

What's happening is something close to this:

```
dict_ = {}
for key, val in zip(["A1","A1","A2"], ["B1","B2","B3"]):
    print(key, val)
    dict_[key] = val
    print(dict_)
```

Output:

```
A1 B1
{'A1': 'B1'}
A1 B2
{'A1': 'B2'}
A2 B3
{'A1': 'B2', 'A2': 'B3'}
```

---

Rather you can try this:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').agg(list).T.to_dict(orient='list')
{'A1': [['B1', 'B2']], 'A2': [['B3']]}
```

Or,

```
>>> df.groupby('A').agg(list).T.to_dict(orient='records')[0]
{'A1': ['B1', 'B2'], 'A2': ['B3']}
```

Comment: Thanks. One more things, Can you please tell me why it select 'B2' not 'B1'? I mean in which logic it identify  which one this function will give when it found multiple values.

Comment: @MdZiaulHaque That is because `B2` is the latest value for key `A1`. Check the edit.